# Javascript Updating 'global' array with value from within a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, scope

Yesterday, I needed help & was introduced to Closures (Im still struggling with that one).

At the start of the function, I created arrays, which need to be populated with values as created within the child function. I had an understanding that 'return' would simply return the values & update the array magically, apparently it doesnt happen that way. I tried push as well but again, no magic.

```
eEndDesigning.onclick = publicity;

function publicity() {
    var eCamerasArray = $(".cCameras").toArray();

    // this is the array that needs to be updated with the annon. func. inside setTimeout func.
    var iLeftPosArray = [];

    // this is the second array that needs to be updated
    var iTopPosArray = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < eCamerasArray.length; i++) {
        var timer = Math.floor(Math.random() * 300) + 100;
        (function(i) // a closure function
        {
            window.setTimeout(function() {
    // following two values are the ones that need to be fed back to 'global' arrays
                iLeftPosArray[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 139) + 360;
                iTopPosArray[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 160) + 100;
                $(eCamerasArray[i]).animate({
                    left: iLeftPosArray[i] + "px",
                    top: iTopPosArray[i] + "px"
                }, 100, "linear");
                return [iLeftPosArray[i], iTopPosArray[i]];
            }, timer);
        }(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Is there a reason you need the Timeout?

Comment: Sorry to break the spell but there is nothing magic out there :-) What do you actually wanna do? Your question is not clear.

Comment: Re the Timeout, yes, so that the obj. animate at random interval within specified limits. @KarlMendes, yes, I want to reuse the values already calculated (iLeftPosArray[i]) to animate other objects within a certain distance of the original obj.

Comment: Returning values from any sort of event handler (including a timer handler, as in your case) only communicates to the browser's event dispatching mechanism.  Returning application data, therefore, never makes sense.

Comment: @DidierGhys, I want to update the empty arrays (see the comment in the code) with values as calculated inside the function in setTimeout. Basically, I am struggling with scoping and want to update the global array with value calculated inside a sub func.

Comment: @Pointy, the array needs to store the value of randomly generated func. (Math.random()). As I need to reuse the values, I figured it would be handy to store them in an array so they can be used again.

Comment: You can store values wherever you like. My point is that the `return` statement at the end of your timer handler makes no sense, as the browser will throw the returned value away.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to move the arrays `iLeftPosArray` and `iTopPosArray` one level up, as they are currently not global, but have the scope of the function.

Comment: I was trying to be clever and keep the scole of 'iLeftPosArray' inside the function as thats where its only needed.